# USSD Application flow... How to design or program?

Tags: ussd

How to design and USSD Application flow.
We will be getting just the unique session of the user and user input.

Comment: In this other [question][1] you will find the answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492272/design-pattern-suggestion-for-ussd

Answer (score 0):

My approach was:

A HashMap<msisdn, Finite State Machine>().

You can use this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492272/design-pattern-suggestion-for-ussd) for more information.