# How to manage request sessions in Java USSD

Tags: java, servlets, ussd

How can I manage requests from USSD gateway in my Java servlet application?
I just need a sort of pseudocode on how I can distinguish between requests, i.e sessions .
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902729/java-ussd-menu-tree-generation-how-to) link helped me get a clue but I still have a problem.